# phpMyAdmin showing blank page on my apache httpd

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have created a server using the Apache httpd, mysql and PHP. I have installed phpmyadmin. but if I try to access through my browser I am getting a blank page instead of login. what I can do for this?

Comment: You could check what error you get inside your http servers error log file.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment as my reputation isn't high enough on here.
However, if you post the steps you've already implemented I'm sure somebody can help. As it is you've given no helpful information.

A few things to check:

Have you checked your apache error logs?

```
/var/log/httpd/error_log
```

Have you created a 'Directory' directive to allow permission?

```
<Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

Have you added an alias in your httpd.conf or virtual host configuration to enable access?

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable php logging using the instruction mentioned here:- [enter link description here](http://perishablepress.com/how-to-enable-php-error-logging-via-htaccess/)

By checking the php log you can make sure whether it's been caused by high memory requirement. 
Also make sure the permissions & ownerships of the phpmyadmin files are correct.